# Infinite sum and Jacobi Theta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, special-functions

I have encountered a sum as following:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} q^{n^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 q^{n^2}
\end{equation}

where $0<q<1$.
I know that the first sum is related to Jacobi Theta function, but what about second sum? Can I do anything about that?

Comment: Hint: What's the derivative of the first sum w.r.t. $q$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt:  That derivative is $\frac{1}{2} \text{EllipticTheta}^{(0,0,1)}(3,0,q)$.  What next?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That's pretty much the end of the line, to my knowledge at least.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork As [Wolfram](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticThetaPrime4/introductions/JacobiThetas/ShowAll.html) claims, the derivatives of the jacobi theta functions cannot be expressed in terms of other special functions.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt do you guys know any approximation for Theta function? So I can use that instead?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork do you guys know any approximation for Theta function? So I can use that instead?

Comment: For the range of $q$ you have set, the series itself is a fairly good approximation: it converges faster than a geometric series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first sum, we have a [Jacobi Theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html), just as you claim.

$$\vartheta_3(q)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}\\\frac12(\vartheta_3(q)-1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n^2}$$

Take the derivative w.r.t. $q$ and you will find that

$$\frac12\vartheta_3'(q)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2q^{n^2-1}$$

$$\frac q2\vartheta_3'(q)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2q^{n^2}$$

Though one cannot improve on this form, according to [Wolfram](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticThetaPrime4/introductions/JacobiThetas/ShowAll.html).  Note these series representations themselves converge extremely fast for $|q|<1$, so I'm not quite sure on any forms that would converge faster.

But anyways, if that's what you want,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2q^{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[4n^2(q^4)^{n^2}+(-1)^{n+1}n^2q^{n^2}\right]$$

$$\frac q2\vartheta_3'(q)=2q^4\vartheta_3'(q^4)-\frac q2\vartheta_4'(q)$$

Repeatedly apply this and you will get

> $$\frac q2\vartheta_3'(q)=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{2n-1}q^{4^{n-1}}\vartheta_4'(q^{4^n})$$

Answer (score 4):

In the realm of the functions used herein,
different conventions exist in what to use for $q$
and what differentiation operator to use.
Therefore, let me do some declarations first.

**Notation:**
Lattices in $\mathbb{C}$ are characterized by their complex *period ratio*
$\tau$ which is taken such that its imaginary part is positive.
Define $q = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau)$
and more generally $q_n = \exp\frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau}{n}$
for positive integer $n$.
We will interpret expressions using $q$ or some $q_n$ as being
functions of $\tau$.

I will use the differentiation operator
$$\dot{(\ )} = \frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\frac{\mathrm{d}(\ )}{\mathrm{d}\tau}
= q\frac{\mathrm{d}(\ )}{\mathrm{d}q}
= \frac{1}{n}q_n\frac{\mathrm{d}(\ )}{\mathrm{d}q_n}$$

The $q$ used in the question would be written $q_2$ in this answer.

Some related well known functions:

- Dedekind eta function:
  $$\eta(\tau) = q_{24}\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1 - q^n)
   = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} (-1)^k q_{24}^{(6k-1)^2}$$
- Jacobi thetanulls:
  $$\begin{align}
   \Theta_{00}(\tau)
   &= \frac{\eta^2\!\left(\frac{\tau+1}{2}\right)}{\eta(\tau+1)}
   = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} q_2^{k^2},
   & \text{aka $\theta_3(0,q_2)$,}
   \\\Theta_{01}(\tau)
   &= \frac{\eta^2\!\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)}{\eta(\tau)}
   = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} (-1)^k q_2^{k^2},
   & \text{aka $\theta_4(0,q_2)$,}
   \\\Theta_{10}(\tau)
   &= \frac{2\eta^2(2\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}
   = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} q_8^{(2k+1)^2},
   & \text{aka $\theta_2(0,q_2)$,}
    \end{align}$$
- Eisenstein series $\operatorname{E}_2(\tau)$,
  also known as Ramanujan's $P(q)$:
  $$\begin{align}
   \operatorname{E}_2(\tau)
   &= P(q) = 24\frac{\dot{\eta}(\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}
   = 1 - 24\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\,q^n}{1 - q^n}
   = 1 - 24\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma(n)\,q^n
    \end{align}$$
  where $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d\mid n}d$ is the divisor sum.

**Answer:**
You look for an identity involving
$$\frac{1}{2}q_2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}q_2}\left(\theta_3(0,q_2) - 1\right)
= \dot{\Theta}_{00}(\tau)$$

- Since the Jacobi thetanulls are eta quotients, their logarithmic derivatives
  can be expressed using $\operatorname{E}_2$:
  $$\begin{align}
   \frac{\dot{\Theta}_{00}(\tau)}{\Theta_{00}(\tau)}
   &= \frac{1}{24}\left(\operatorname{E}_2\!\left(\frac{\tau+1}{2}\right)
   - \operatorname{E}_2(\tau)\right)
   = \frac{1}{24}\left(P(-q_2) - P(q)\right)
   \\&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \sigma_{\bar{\mathrm{u}}}(n)\,q_2^n
   \qquad\text{(power series)}
   \\&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}n\,q_2^{n}}{1 - q_2^{2n}}
   \qquad\text{(Lambert-like series)}
   \\&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q_2^{2n-1}}{\left(1 + q_2^{2n-1}\right)^2}
   \qquad\text{(transformed)}
   \\\text{where}\quad
   \sigma_{\bar{\mathrm{u}}}(n)
   &= \sum_{\substack{d\mid n\\2d\nmid n}} d
   \qquad\text{(sum of divisors whose cofactors are odd)}
    \end{align}$$
  Above, *transformed* means: Express the summand fractions as power series,
  swap the summation's nesting order, and simplify the new inner series.
- Such logarithmic derivatives of Jacobi thetanulls are known
  as *Halphen's Psi functions*. Define
  $$\begin{align}
   \Psi_{00}(\tau) &= \frac{\dot{\Theta}_{00}(\tau)}{\Theta_{00}(\tau)}
   &\Psi_{01}(\tau) &= \frac{\dot{\Theta}_{01}(\tau)}{\Theta_{01}(\tau)}
   &\Psi_{10}(\tau) &= \frac{\dot{\Theta}_{10}(\tau)}{\Theta_{10}(\tau)}
    \end{align}$$
  There are a lot of identities relating the Jacobi thetanulls,
  and those can be translated into identities for the Psi functions.
  Furthermore, series representations for the Psi functions can be obtained
  via $\operatorname{E}_2$, as shown above for $\Psi_{00}$.
  Related OEIS sequences: [A186690](https://oeis.org/A186690),
  [A002131](https://oeis.org/A002131),
  [A002129](https://oeis.org/A002129).
  I will not cover the details here. However, some aspects are particularly
  interesting, so I will mention them here.
- Pairwise differences of Psi functions can be expressed in terms of
  thetanulls:
  $$\begin{align}
   \Psi_{10} - \Psi_{01} &= \frac{\Theta_{00}^4}{8}
   &\Psi_{10} - \Psi_{00} &= \frac{\Theta_{01}^4}{8}
   &\Psi_{00} - \Psi_{01} &= \frac{\Theta_{10}^4}{8}
    \end{align}$$
  Consequently, when differentiating a quotient of two Jacobi thetanulls,
  the result can be expressed without Psi functions. Example:
  $$\left(\frac{\Theta_{10}}{\Theta_{00}}\right)^{\cdot}
    = (\Psi_{10} - \Psi_{00})\frac{\Theta_{10}}{\Theta_{00}}
    = \frac{\Theta_{01}^4}{8}\frac{\Theta_{10}}{\Theta_{00}}$$
  This also implies that we can express $\Theta_{00}^4,
    \Theta_{01}^4,\Theta_{10}^4$
  in terms of the Eisenstein series $\operatorname{E}_2$.
- For further differentiation, we need to know how to express
  derivatives of the Psi functions. To cut things short, the result is
  $$\begin{align}
   \dot{\Psi}_{00} &= 2\left(
   \Psi_{00}\,\Psi_{01}
   + \Psi_{00}\,\Psi_{10}
   - \Psi_{01}\,\Psi_{10}\right)
   \\\dot{\Psi}_{01} &= 2\left(
   \Psi_{00}\,\Psi_{01}
   + \Psi_{01}\,\Psi_{10}
   - \Psi_{00}\,\Psi_{10}\right)
   \\\dot{\Psi}_{10} &= 2\left(
   \Psi_{00}\,\Psi_{10}
   + \Psi_{01}\,\Psi_{10}
   - \Psi_{00}\,\Psi_{01}\right)
    \end{align}$$
  An equivalent formulation is
  $$\begin{align}
   \dot{\Psi}_{01} + \dot{\Psi}_{10} &= 4\,\Psi_{01}\,\Psi_{10}
   \\\dot{\Psi}_{00} + \dot{\Psi}_{10} &= 4\,\Psi_{00}\,\Psi_{10}
   \\\dot{\Psi}_{00} + \dot{\Psi}_{01} &= 4\,\Psi_{00}\,\Psi_{01}
    \end{align}$$
- Whenever you run into expressions crowded with $\operatorname{E}_2$
  and its derivatives, Halphen's Psi functions offer nicely symmetric
  expressions for substitution:
  $$\begin{align}
   \frac{\operatorname{E}_2}{8}
   &= \Psi_{00} + \Psi_{01} + \Psi_{10}
   \\\frac{\dot{\operatorname{E}}_2}{16}
   &= \Psi_{00}\,\Psi_{01}
   + \Psi_{00}\,\Psi_{10}
   + \Psi_{01}\,\Psi_{10}
   \\\frac{\ddot{\operatorname{E}}_2}{192}
   &= \Psi_{00}\,\Psi_{01}\,\Psi_{10}
    \end{align}$$
- Applying the above, you will find that some higher derivatives
  can be expressed without Psi functions. Example:
  $$\left(\frac{1}{\Theta_{00}^2}\right)^{\cdot\cdot}
    = -\frac{1}{16}\,\frac{\Theta_{01}^4\,\Theta_{10}^4}{\Theta_{00}^2}$$
  You are invited to find the second derivatives of
  $\Theta_{01}^{-2}$ and $\Theta_{10}^{-2}$ as an exercise.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. +1 looks like it surpassed the identities given in Whittaker and Watson.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thanks. It should be possible to formulate an answer in terms of $E$ and $K$. For large enough $\Im\tau$, that is, unless branch cuts of $E$ or $K$ interfere, we should have $(E-k'^2K)K=2\pi^2\Psi_{00}$, $(E-K)K=2\pi^2\Psi_{01}$, $EK=2\pi^2\Psi_{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

A series expansion of an Elliptic Theta function (up to order 100) is:

$1-2 q+2 q^4-2 q^9+2 q^{16}-2 q^{25}+2 q^{36}-2 q^{49}+2 q^{64}-2 q^{81}+2
   q^{100}+O\left(q^{101}\right)$